# ensure local branch commits/pushes to right remote branch

Tags: git, github

When I run "git remote show guarddog", I am expecting to see something like this:

```
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    guarddoglocal pushes to master
```

However, this is actually what I do see:

```
git remote show guarddog
Username for 'github.com': 
Password for 'github.com': 
* remote guarddog
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/guarddog/guarddog.git
  Push  URL: https://github.com/guarddog/guarddog.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    guarddoglocal merges with remote master
```

Clearly, guarddoglocal is not configured for git push to guarddog/master.

This is what I done so far:

```
git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/usera/usera.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/usera/usera.git (push)

git remote add guarddog https://github.com/guarddog/guarddog.git
git remote -v
guarddog    https://github.com/guarddog/guarddog.git (fetch)
guarddog    https://github.com/guarddog/guarddog.git (push)
origin          https://github.com/usera/usera.git (fetch)
origin          https://github.com/usera/usera.git (push)

git status
# On branch useralocal
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   app/assets/javascripts/application.js.erb

git push guarddog useralocal:master

git checkout -b guarddoglocal guarddog/master

git branch
* guarddoglocal
  useralocal

git status
# On branch guarddoglocal
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   app/assets/javascripts/application.js.erb

git remote show guarddog
Username for 'github.com': 
Password for 'github.com': 
* remote guarddog
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/guarddog/guarddog.git
  Push  URL: https://github.com/guarddog/guarddog.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master tracked
      Local branch configured for 'git pull':
        guarddoglocal merges with remote master
```

As you can see, the pull looks reasonable, but the default push does not. When I push on branch guarddoglocal, I need to ensure it pushes to the guarddog remote repository.

Trying something like this doesn't change anything:

```
git push -u guarddoglocal guarddog:master
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using the `-u` option wrongly

```
git push -u guarddog      guarddoglocal:master
            ^^^^^^^^      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^
            remote name   local branch  remote branch
```

while in the `guarddoglocal` branch will configure it to track the `master` branch on the `guarddog` remote.

Comment: That command gave me errors: error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/guarddog/guarddog.git'

Comment: my bad, I forgot one part, try now

Comment: That works, but why can't I just do git push? When I run "git remote show guarddog" it still shows that the push is not configured by default to push to the guarddog master remote.

Comment: any ideas of how I can configure it so I just need to run "git push" like when I clone projects?

Comment: Ok but when I run git remote show, it still doesn't say "  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    guarddoglocal pushes to master". Usually when I clone projects I see that section.

Comment: I frankly don't know why. I usually just use the `-u` option to configure the default remote without caring too much about the internal representation